# Yum update error on RHEL 8 with Team Viewer installed: Failed to download metadata for repo 'tvinternal_dev'

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, teamviewer

I have an Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 as vm guest OS in Hyper-V. And I have installed the TeamViewer 15.5.3.

But when I run the update command below:

```
yum update --nobest --skip-broken
```

I got such error:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
gitlab_gitlab-ee                                                                              134  B/s | 862  B     00:06    
TeamViewer Internal (Dev Nightly Packages) - x86_64                                           0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:16    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'tvinternal_dev':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://lnxrelease-02/yum/stable/main/binary-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Could not resolve host: lnxrelease-02]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'tvinternal_dev': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

It looks like the team-viewer set the wrong repository release url `http://lnxrelease-02/yum/stable/main/binary-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml` in the interal_dev version. And I have no idea the correct one.

So I tried to disable the repository `tvinternal_dev` via the command:

```
sudo subscription-manager repos --disable 'tvinternal_dev'
```

It says: 
`Error: 'tvinternal_dev' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.`

After I run the command `subscription-manager repos --list` as suggested, I cannot see the repository `tvinternal_dev`.

What should I do to skip/disable the repository `tvinternal_dev` to continue the updating process? Otherwise, do I have chance to correct the release URl of TeamViewer such kind of `inreral_dev` repository?

I am new to the Linux and any suggestion will be graceful. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652226/13378146) Here is the answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved by disabling not only tvinternal_dev, but also tvinternal_it and teamviewer:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled tvinternal_dev
sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled tvinternal_it
sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled teamviewer
```

Then I issued: 
    sudo dnf update 
and it worked fine. I guess we will have to reinstall teamviewer. I hope it helps.

PS: perhaps the problem with your command is that you used 'tvinternal_dev' (= with single quotes).

Comment: Thanks for your comments.